# Can we remove the communication tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

The tag wiki for [communication](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/communication) currently reads

> For questions involving interactions with other people, outside the standard conversation that you can have. This includes body movements and also other forms of non-verbal communication.

That sounds really broad. Pretty much any question on this site could be tagged with this tag.

Could this tag be removed please. If you want, you can make tags for more specific forms of communication, e.g. [nonverbal-communication](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nonverbal-communication) or [telephone](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/telephone)

Comment: Down to burninate the tag, but I would say that instead of making it disappear, we need to edit each question with a "branched" tag, such as [telephone] or [confrontations] or whatever new tags we create.

Comment: Is "burninate" a specialized term on here or is it a @Zizouz212-ism? <-- Semi-real question.

Comment: @WeaselADAPT see: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate/239191#239191

Comment: @Shog9 oh! wow, that's very helpful. thanks for noticing i was really asking!

Comment: Burniate, and blacklist. It _will_ be infinitely resurrected elsewise.

Answer (score 8):

As you say, almost everything in interpersonal skills is a form of [communication](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/communication).

This is a meta tag. If you're asking a question about a specific form of communication, that tag is preferable (e.g. [emails](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/emails), [texting](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/texting)).

If this post gets support, the mods can request the CMs blacklist the tag to prevent it being recreated. This is better done before the tag gets too unwieldy.

Right now it's used on 45 questions and the only question it's the sole tag on is closed. This means that it should be pretty easy to review the questions with the tag currently and, if necessary, replace the tag with something more specific. This tag is regularly used with [conversations](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conversations), which should be an acceptable replacement for in-person communication in the way email and texts are for written communication.

Comment: Full support: burninate it. I hope the removal doesn't affect the active questions feed by flooding it with all the 45 questions.

Comment: @NVZ Mods can remove tags without affecting the active questions if we delete the tag entirely rather than manually removing it.

Comment: Well, that's good news. Just like the Community user replaced all http with https and changed all meta.sitename URLs to sitename.meta silently.

Comment: @NVZ Oh those are coming to the top of the front page? I don't think that was supposed to do that, but oh well :/

Comment: @Zizouz212 They're edits because we're replacing the bad tag with the tags we want to keep... so we have to edit them. We can't add a tag without bumping the post.

Comment: @Zizouz212 LOL. I've retagged some. The rest will be silently killed off.

Comment: Oh, I was referring to the Community script.

Comment: @Zizouz212 Community can't add tags. It can replace them when you do a merge or synonym but there's no one "correct" tag to replace them with, so they have to be done manually.

Comment: @Catija I think we're talking way past each other :) I'm referring to the community script that updates SE links from http to https, and fixes meta links. Not tagging. I also completely misread NVZ's comment :P

Comment: @Zizouz212 What confused you? The Community user does not retag. Which is why we did so manually. The Community user can remove tags without flooding the active feed, so we're waiting for the CMs to ban the *communication* tag instead of manually removing those.