# Do [profanity] and [stutter] need their own tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

Wouldn't both [profanity](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/profanity) and [stutter](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stutter) come under speaking? (and profanity come under either [online-interactions](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/online-interactions) or [communication](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/communication) for written?) I don't think we need specifics in regards to both aspects of these. I would happily untag the questions under these tags, but it'd be nice to have to input on this also.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Every topic on the site falls under the the tag "interpersonal"... Which is blacklisted for that reason. Arguably the same could be said of [communication](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/communication), since the vast majority of questions here concern communication, including the top tag [conversations](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conversations)...

...Which is to say, you could get rid of pretty much everything here except for [communication](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/communication) and the various locale tags.

Surely that doesn't sound like a good idea?

A tag is too narrow if there can **ever** only be one question in it. In practice, a tag is just noise if, after some reasonable period of time, there *is* only one question in it (in fact, the system deletes such tags after 6 months unless someone took the time to write a wiki for it - so, uh, don't waste your time writing wikis unless you *know* a tag is gonna be useful).

Beyond that, narrowness stops being so important; what matters is that the tag actually applies to the question it hangs off of: using the [profanity](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/profanity) tag on questions that happen to mention the profane in passing is a waste, but if folks are asking questions *about* profanity, surely a profanity tag is warranted!

The guidance on the sidebar of [the Ask Question page](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) includes these two bullets:

- use tags that describe things or concepts that are essential, not incidental to your question
- favor using existing popular tags

If you start with the most popular (likely broadest) applicable tag and keep going until you can't find anything else essential to the question *or* hit the limit of 5 tags, a set of reasonable tags should emerge fairly quickly (thus making it easier to pick relevant tags for future questions). Until that happens - until this site can be said to represent a solid cross-section of knowledge on interpersonal skills (*without* laughing) - then worrying about tags being too narrow is not a good use of your time.

Comment: If anyone is interested, here is the link to the proposal to remove the communication tag: https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1323/can-we-remove-the-communication-tag